# Lambda expression to find of a number is composite or not

Tags: java, lambda

```
private static boolean isCompositeLambda(int number) {
        return number > 3 && Stream.iterate(2, i -> i + 1)
                                   .filter(x -> number % x == 0)
                                   .limit((long) Math.sqrt(number))
                                   .count() > 0;
    }
```

When i give 5 it goes into infinite loop.
Can anyone give the correct code

Comment: The limit is the number of values, not the limit of the value, which the filter would prevent anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems, the filter is applied first, and the second is the limit is the number of values, not the value it self.

It goes into an very long (but not infinite) loop because it take a long time to generate your limit of numbers. e.g. for 5 it tries to get 2 numbers ((long) Math.sqrt(5)) == 2L, however to achieve the first solution when `number == x` however it has to check another ~4 billion values before it overflows and reaches `-number` to get a second solution and the limit is reached. i.e. 5 % 5 == 0 and 5 % -5 == 0

A simpler solution is

```
private static boolean isCompositeLambda(int number) {
    return number > 3 && 
           IntStream.rangeClosed(2, (int) Math.sqrt(number))
                    .anyMatch(x -> number % x == 0);
}
```